# access value of variable from iframe at the parent level

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've read countless answers to similar questions but I'm just not getting the result I need.

For background... I've got an iframe embedded into my page. Both the parent and iframe are on the same domain. I have some variables within the iframe that I'd like to have access to within the parent page.

The html on the parent page that serves the iframe is like this;

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="one-time-form" width="100%" height="1850px" src="https://www.domain-that-parent-and-iframe-reside-on.com/page-url-for-iframe"></iframe>
```

Within that iframe src is a variable that stores an array of data. This variable is called `var useableData`

I know that my iframe is loading later than the parent page so I've got my attempt at calling this variable housed within a jQuery function that runs once the whole window is finished loading.

**jQuery**

```
$(window).load(function () {
   var fName = $("#one-time-form").contentWindow.useableData;
   console.log(fName);
});
```

This just returns a console error of *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'useableData' of undefined*

Any ideas for why this isn't working or modifications to my approach I should take?

**UPDATE**

Have tried implementing a `postMessage()` but it's not co-operating either. I've based it off of this demo: https://usefulangle.com/post/4/javascript-communication-parent-child-window

In the child page I've got this running:

**Child Message**

```
  //Function to send data back to the parent window
  function ProcessChildMessage(message) {
     var testMessage = useableData;
  }
```

Then in the parent page I'm calling this function

**Parent Message**

```
window.opener.ProcessChildMessage('Message to the parent');
```

Still not having any luck with this and am seeing this console error "*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ProcessChildMessage' of null*"

Comment: The `load` event occurs when the DOM has loaded, but scripts may not have run yet. You probably should use the `postMessage()` mechanism to communicate between the iframe and parent.

Comment: BTW, the function form of the `load` event handler is deprecated, you should use `.on("load", function...)`

Comment: `$("#one-time-form")` returns a jQuery, not a native Element. You might try doing `$("#one-time-form")[0].contentWindow` or `$('#one-time-form').get(0).contentWindow`

Answer (score 1):

`contentWindow` is a property of a native window; you're trying to call it on a jQuery object.

Change

```
$("#one-time-form").contentWindow.useableData;
```

to

```
$("#one-time-form")[0].contentWindow.useableData;
```

Comment: This is clearing the console log so we're making some progress! But the value returned is saying it's undefined

Answer (score 0):

You're running this when the main window has loaded, you need to wait for the iframe to be loaded.

And as mentioned in another answer, `contentWindow` is a DOM property, not a jQuery property, so you need to access the iframe DOM element directly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#one-time-form").on("load", function() {
        var fName = document.getElementById("one-time-form").contentWindow.useableData;
        console.log(fName);
    });
});
```

Comment: utilizing this approach and accessing the correct contentWindow as mentioned in the other answer is clearing the console error but still returning an undefined variable. Is this answer meant to address the way the function is loaded? It seems like I'm still not running this function after the iframe finishes loading

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment above, you might need to use the message interface to wait for the JS in the iframe to finish.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar - have you got enough experience with the message interface that you could help craft a sample for me to try?

Comment: How is `usableData` assigned in the iframe? Is it done synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: If you make an attempt, I can help if it doesn't work.

Comment: It's populated within the success function of an AJAX call

Comment: Then clearly it won't be done when the DOM is first loaded.

Comment: The success function should use `postMessage()` to send the value to the parent window.

Comment: You should add these details to the question, it makes a big difference in how to solve it.

Comment: Well when I log all the functions out in the console this function with the on load is the last to run, I've got a bunch of logs showing me vars from the AJAX call that are showing ahead of this one... anyways I thought I might have had this all in the right order - perhaps not! Will give the postMessage() a try in the success function. Appreciate all the help and pointing me in the right direction

Comment: gave it a try with the postMessage but I'm not seeing any success here yet

Comment: You don't call `postMessage()`. The parent window needs to use `$(window).on("message", function(e) ...)` to receive the message.